# Check if canonical header is set in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers

I need to find a way to check if there is set a canonical URL via htaccess. If no canonical URL set then execute rewriterule

already tried %{HTTP:link} and %{HTTP:X-link} and %{HTTP:Link} and %{HTTP:X-Link}

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^album=113$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Link} !canonical [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ https://old.mydomain.be/gallery/$1 [L,P,QSA,NC]
```

If canonical header set passthrough the content from old.mydomain.be. Now it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The Link header is a response header. You can only redirect based on request headers in .htaccess.